# Why is this Rabin-Karp Code, in Python, so slow?

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime, rabin-karp

```
from time import process_time_ns
def initial_hash(desired):
    u=0
    for i in desired:
        u=(u*256+ord(i))%89
    return u
def find(Document):
    initial=Document[:len(desired)]
    hash_1=initial_hash(initial)
    for i in range(1,len(Document)-len(desired)+1):
        hash_1=skip(Document[i-1],hash_1)
        hash_1=append(Document[len(desired)+i-1],hash_1)
def append(char,u):
    u=(u*256+ord(char))%89
    return u
def skip(char,u):
    u=(u-(ord(char)*(constante)))%89
    return u
to=process_time_ns()
desired="ababa"
constante=(256**(len(desired)-1))%89
hash_desired=initial_hash(desired)
text=open("match.txt","r")
for x in text:
    find(x)
print(process_time_ns()-to)
```

I have implemented this code by following the MIT course 6006. I used in the code above some markers to see the time. I changed the `match.txt`to a lot of different sizes as well as the `desirable` variable, the one I want to find in the document. But for a lot of variations the naive algorithm described in the link is always faster. I choose 89 as prime. The code is based on this link:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/MIT6_006F11_lec09_orig.pdf

Comment: It's the "simple algorithm" in the link. You do: `Document[ i :len(desired)+i]` and compare with `desired` until achieve the final of `Document`

Answer (score 1):

Rabin--Karp has a better worst-case asymptotic running time than the naive algorithm. Both qualifiers are important: naive has a linear-time best and average case, and the constant on this best case is better than Rabin--Karp, so in a lot of cases it will actually be faster. If you want to see a big difference, choose a bad input for naive like searching for `aaaa(many repetitions of a)aaaab` in `aaaa(many more repetitions of a)aaaab`.